# Different kinds of instance of Child- Parent class hierarchy in c#

Tags: c#, oop

I want to know the relation between instances of parent child in c#.

Suppose you have two classes Base and Derived:

`Base b = new Base()
Derived d = new Derived()
Derived db = new Base()
Base bd = new Derived()`

then what is the meaning of above types of objects

Please suggest I am confused.

Comment: `Derived db = new Base()` is not possible

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi Base may inherit Derived ;)

Comment: this is really too broad: please try reading any basic article/book on inheritance (like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx) and come back with more specific questions if you have doubts

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Base is actually the base class of Derived....

Line 1 contains an instance of the base class.

Line 2 contains a instance of the Derived class.

These are both "standard" variables, where the variable type exactly matches the instance it contains.

Line 4 is an instance of derived class, but restricted to only accessing base class methods.  Think of it as a slightly restricted view of the derived class.

Line 3 should produce a compilation error.  You can't place an instance of a base class in to a variable of a more restrictive type.  Think of it like this "All Dogs(derived class) are Animals(base class), but not all Animals are Dogs.

Comment: Bradley Thanks a lot it M pretty much clear now.